# Visual Basic - draw a random number of the same size circles (5 – 10) across the form each in random color using a loop

Tags: vb.net

I have this code that I wrote up, but this code was used when I left clicked on the form, but wasn't a random number of circles. I am wondering how I can adapt it to draw 5-10 random circles with random colors across the form when I click a button, but it has to use a loop. Thanks!!

```
Private Sub CirclePainterForm_MouseDown(ByVal sender As _
    Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) _
    Handles MyBase.MouseDown

        Dim graphicsObject As Graphics = CreateGraphics()
        Dim randomObject As Random = New Random
        Dim diameter As Integer = randomObject.Next(5, 200)

        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            graphicsObject.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(RandomColor()), e.X, e.Y, _
            diameter, diameter)

            graphicsObject.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(RandomColor()), e.X + 250, e.Y, _
            diameter + 50, diameter + 50)

            graphicsObject.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(RandomColor()), e.X + 500, e.Y, _
            diameter + 75, diameter + 75)

            graphicsObject.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(RandomColor()), e.X + 750, e.Y, _
            diameter + 100, diameter + 100)

            graphicsObject.FillEllipse(New SolidBrush(RandomColor()), e.X + 1000, e.Y, _
            diameter + 125, diameter + 125)
```

Comment: anybody have any insight? This draws circles, just not how I'm looking to do it. Please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a button to your form and add code for the Click event:

To do Circles Or Squares [and updated with your/my comments]

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim rnd As New Random(), rndCol As New Random(DateTime.Now.Ticks Mod ((rnd.Next) + 1))
    Dim numShapes = rnd.Next(5, 11), bIsCircleOrSquare As Boolean = (rnd.Next Mod 2)

    Using g = Me.CreateGraphics()
        g.Clear(Me.BackColor)
        Dim diam = rnd.Next(55, Math.Min(255, ClientSize.Width))
        While numShapes > 0
            Using b As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(rndCol.Next(100, 256), rndCol.Next(256), rndCol.Next(256), rndCol.Next(256)))
                Dim x = rnd.Next(ClientSize.Width - diam), y = rnd.Next(ClientSize.Height - diam)
                If bIsCircleOrSquare Then
                    g.FillRectangle(b, x, y, diam, diam)
                    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, x, y, diam, diam)
                Else
                    g.FillEllipse(b, x, y, diam, diam)
                    g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, x, y, diam, diam)
                End If
            End Using
            numShapes -= 1
        End While
    End Using

End Sub
```

If you want to see the circles overlap you can replace:

```
 Using b As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(rndCol.Next(100,256), rndCol.Next(256), rndCol.Next(256), rndCol.Next(256)))
```

with

```
 Using b As New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, rndCol.Next(256), rndCol.Next(256), rndCol.Next(256)))
```

Comment: also, how would I change that to make a square loop? I have such a simple line of code, but not sure how to make it in a loop. Need 10 squares, random size (but all the same), same color. Thanks again!! graphicsObject.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.Black), e.X, e.Y, 200, 200)

Comment: it is a for loop. If you need to do it with a while loop change the `for ...` to `while numCircles > 0` and change 'next' to `loop` and add `numCircles -= 1` inside the loop. If you want it to do Squares change the `FillEllipse` and `DrawEllipse` to `FillRectangle` and `DrawRectangle`

Comment: Be advised that anything drawn in this manner will disappear if the form is minimized, repainted, or if another window is dragged across it.  Drawing should be performed in the OnPaint override or Paint event.  Also the CreateGraphics call should be avoided.